# Пользователи не могут зарегистрироваться в Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-android

В Андроид приложение добавил Firebase Auth, если тестирую на своих устройствах или эмуляторах, то всё работает отлично. Даже есть некоторые пользователи, у которых получается регистрироваться, но меньшинство если сравнивать с остальными у которых не получается это сделать. UI регистрации очень простая, просто вводишь Email,Password,NickName и нажимаешь кнопку регистрации.

Вот код отвечающий за регистрацию:

```
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(regEmail.getText().toString()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(regPassword.getText().toString()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(regName.getText().toString())){
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(regEmail.getText().toString(),regPassword.getText().toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Регистрация прошла успешно", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, UserProfile.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            writeNewUser();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Что-то пошло не так", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            problemText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                    }
                });
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Что-то пошло не так", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        problemText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       
    }
```

Comment: Берём ошибку `task.getException()` и проверяем почему "Что-то пошло не так". Может юзеры вводят что попало вместо почты или пароль 12345

Comment: Да, после того как написал вопрос я вспомнил про task.getException(). Каждый раз когда будет выходить ошибка, в базу будет отправляться эта ошибка. Посмотрим, что за ошибка у них там. Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Вам нужно обрабатывать их в коде, а не просто собирать. Как-то так, видимо: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48503254/15923106

Comment: Да, я буду обрабатывать в коде, но сначала же надо выяснить в чем вообще причина. Пользователи не идут на обратную связь. Лишь некоторые пишут о том что проблема с регистрацией

Comment: Вообще, спасибо за ответ как именно обрабатывать. Т.к после этого шага, я бы все равно искал ответ на вопрос "Как обрабатывать"